# Send data from vue.js project to a api/file.php inside it

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, vue.js

Hello I'm trying to send data to an api/file.php inside my Vue project that inserts data sent into a database. I'm getting an error

[image]

This is the code for the request... Made from App.vue to api/recipes.php who's one level above.

[image]

The code I was using worked in an example where I made index.php with vue.js and an api/file.php file and used them to communicate with the database. I'm uncertain I know how to access my api on a route? Not even certain if I'm asking the right question. Thank you!

EDIT ////

I started the server @ localhost:8080 on the back-end that I'm trying to get the data from. There I have a get method that serves all data from the database and display as JSON with json_encode($variable). When trying to make the request I'm getting a CORS error.

https://prnt.sc/tzvbhh

Comment: put full url in axios request : http://localhost/api... probably vue js served in http://localhost:8080/ and your apache server in http://localhost/

Comment: Please include code as text [with formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) rather than images.

Comment: @Youssef that answers my question, thank you! Got into a new struggle though I'm getting a CORS error atm. I installed a cors plugin, not so proud of that attempt to fix, but it did not work, I still got an error that the header content is set to * wildstar.